# foreach and for loop copy the duplicate records into Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm building a film database GUI application and I need to convert the arraylist with all the Film information into a 2d array so it'll be accepted by JTable.

It converts it sure enough, but when walking through the program in Eclipse Debug I notice that the for loop algorithm writes the first Film Record into all spaces within the array.

e.g. 
[Movie1Title, Movie1Rating, Movie1Genre][Movie1Title, Movie1Rating, Movie1Genre] 
instead of 
[Movie1Title, Movie1Rating, Movie1Genre][2Title, 2Rating, 2Genre]

then when the loop breaks for the second Film record in the database, it overwrites the first film record with the second record and so on.

At the end of the process, The gui shows a long list of the same record, the last record in the list.

I'm not sure where I got the logic wrong with my loop. Can anyone send me in the right direction?

```
FilmDatabase filmList = new FilmDatabase();
    filmList = filmList.listInput("MainDBTest.txt");

    int listLen = filmList.getFilmDB().size();
    Object[][] filmTable = new Object[listLen][5];

    for (int x = 0; x < listLen; x++) {
        for(Film film : filmList.getFilmDB()) {
            //System.out.println(film);
            filmTable[x][0] = film.getFilmName();
            filmTable[x][1] = film.getFilmRating();
            filmTable[x][2] = film.getReleaseDate();
            filmTable[x][3] = film.getFilmGenre();
            filmTable[x][4] = film.getFilmCast();
            System.out.println(film);
        }
    }

    Object columnNames[] = { "Title", "Rating", "Year", "Genre", "Cast" };
    JTable mainTable = new JTable(filmTable, columnNames);
```

Comment: You don't need 2 for loop... Can you figure it out ? :)

Comment: *"I  need to convert the arraylist with all the Film information into a 2d array so it'll be accepted by JTable*" - you don't have to. You can use a custom `TableModel` which is capable of representing your base `Film` object directly, a much simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to convert the arraylist with all the Film information into a 2d array so it'll be accepted by JTable.

You don't need a 2D array. In fact you don't want to do this.

The `DefaultTableModel` store the data in a Vector of Vectors. The data from the 2D array will be copied to the Vector of Vectors. So using your approach you will have 3 copies of the data:

1. in your ArrayList
2. in the temporary 2D array
3. in the Vector of Vectors.

So if you really want to use this approach, at minimum you should just copy your data to the Vector directly and skip the 2D array. So the code would be something like:

```
Object columnNames[] = { "Title", "Rating", "Year", "Genre", "Cast" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for(Film film : filmList.getFilmDB()) 
{
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(5)
    row.addElement( film.getFilmName() );
    row.addElement( film.getFilmRating() );
    ...
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable mainTable = new JTable(model);
```

Or the better solution is to just create a custom `FilmTableModel` to hold all your Film objects directly.

For a step-by-step example of this approach check out the example in [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).